# Mutual exclusion thread locking, with dropping of queued functions upon mutex/lock release, in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, mutex, critical-section

This is the problem I have: I'm using Python 2.7, and I have a code which runs in a thread, which has a critical region that only one thread should execute at the time. That code currently has no mutex mechanisms, so I wanted to inquire what I could use for my specific use case, which involves "dropping" of "queued" functions. I've tried to simulate that behavior with the following minimal working example:

```python
useThreading=False # True

if useThreading:  from threading import Thread, Lock
else:             from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

mymutex = Lock()

import time
tstart = None

def processData(data):
  #~ mymutex.acquire()
  try:
    print('thread {0} [{1:.5f}] Do some stuff'.format(data, time.time()-tstart))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('thread {0} [{1:.5f}] 1000'.format(data, time.time()-tstart))
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print('thread {0} [{1:.5f}] done'.format(data, time.time()-tstart))
  finally:
    #~ mymutex.release()
    pass

# main:
tstart = time.time()
for ix in xrange(0,3):
  if useThreading: t = Thread(target = processData, args = (ix,))
  else: t = Process(target = processData, args = (ix,))
  t.start()
  time.sleep(0.001)
```

Now, if you run this code, you get a printout like this:

```
thread 0 [0.00173] Do some stuff
thread 1 [0.00403] Do some stuff
thread 2 [0.00642] Do some stuff
thread 0 [0.50261] 1000
thread 1 [0.50487] 1000
thread 2 [0.50728] 1000
thread 0 [1.00330] done
thread 1 [1.00556] done
thread 2 [1.00793] done
```

That is to say, the three threads quickly get "queued" one after another (something like 2-3 ms after each other). Actually, they don't get queued, they simply start executing in parallel after 2-3 ms after each other.

Now, if I enable the `mymutex.acquire()`/`.release()` commands, I get what would be expected:

```
thread 0 [0.00174] Do some stuff
thread 0 [0.50263] 1000
thread 0 [1.00327] done
thread 1 [1.00350] Do some stuff
thread 1 [1.50462] 1000
thread 1 [2.00531] done
thread 2 [2.00547] Do some stuff
thread 2 [2.50638] 1000
thread 2 [3.00706] done
```

Basically, now with locking, the threads don't run in parallel, but they run one after another thanks to the lock - as long as one thread is working, the others will block at the `.acquire()`. But this is not exactly what I want to achieve, either.

What I want to achieve is this: let's assume that when `.acquire()` is first triggered by a thread function, it registers an id of a function (say a pointer to it) in a queue. After that, the behavior is basically the same as with the Lock - while the one thread works, the others block at `.acquire()`. When the first thread is done, it goes in the `finally:` block - and here, I'd like to check to see how many threads are waiting in the queue; then I'd like to delete/drop all waiting threads *except* for the very last one - and finally, I'd `.release()` the lock; meaning that after this, what was the last thread in the queue would execute next. I'd imagine, I would want to write something like the following pseudocode:

```
  ...
  finally:
    if (len(mymutex.queue) > 2): # more than this instance plus one other waiting:
      while (len(mymutex.queue) > 2):
        mymutex.queue.pop(1) # leave alone [0]=this instance, remove next element
    # at this point, there should be only queue[0]=this instance, and queue[1]= what was the last thread queued previously
    mymutex.release() # once we releace, queue[0] should be gone, and the next in the queue should acquire the mutex/lock..
    pass
  ...
```

With that, I'd expect a printout like this:

```
thread 0 [0.00174] Do some stuff
thread 0 [0.50263] 1000
thread 0 [1.00327] done
# here upon lock release, thread 1 would be deleted - and the last one in the queue, thread 2, would acquire the lock next:
thread 2 [1.00350] Do some stuff
thread 2 [1.50462] 1000
thread 2 [2.00531] done
```

What would be the most straightforward way to achieve this in Python?

Comment: I had the same issue and to solve it i used [redis](http://redis.io/) to sync threads and make the last or first one to do some critical code, at your case it can be as a queue, for that you need to know the number of threads at each thread and just publish it to redis.

Comment: Thanks @KobiK - never heard about `redis` before; I'm looking at http://redis.io/commands and http://redis.io/clients and it doesn't really look easy, at least in terms of using it in this context. I'll try to track down some sort of a tutorial... Thanks again - cheers!

Comment: it's not that hard just implement a `Lock` object with `redis.lock` and create a wrapper to use at the critical code, at the implementation use `publish` at each lock request, and check the number of threads if it's you max number then you can release it with your queue option.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, @KobiK - exactly what I need to narrow down my search `:)` Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want a queue-like behaviour, so why not use [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)?

```
import threading
from  Queue import Queue
import time

# threads advertise to this queue when they're waiting
wait_queue = Queue()
# threads get their task from this queue
task_queue = Queue()

def do_stuff():
    print "%s doing stuff" % str(threading.current_thread())
    time.sleep(5)
def queue_thread(sleep_time):

    # advertise current thread waiting
    time.sleep(sleep_time)  
    wait_queue.put("waiting")  

    # wait for permission to pass
    message = task_queue.get()

    print "%s got task: %s" % (threading.current_thread(), message)
    # unregister current thread waiting
    wait_queue.get()

    if message == "proceed":
        do_stuff()
        # kill size-1 threads waiting
        for _ in range(wait_queue.qsize() - 1):
            task_queue.put("die")
        # release last
        task_queue.put("proceed")

    if message == "die":
        print "%s died without doing stuff" % threading.current_thread()
        pass

t1 = threading.Thread(target=queue_thread, args=(1, ))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=queue_thread, args=(2, ))
t3 = threading.Thread(target=queue_thread, args=(3, ))
t4 = threading.Thread(target=queue_thread, args=(4, ))

# allow first thread to pass
task_queue.put("proceed")

t1.start()
t2.start()
t3.start()
t4.start()
```

thread-1 arrives first and "acquires" the section, other threads come later to wait at the queue (and advertise they're waiting). Then, when thread-1 leaves it gives permission to the last thread at the queue by telling all other thread to die, and the last thread to proceed.

You can have finer control using different messages, a typical one would be a thread-id in the `wait_queue` (so you know **who** is waiting, and the order in which it arrived).

You can probably utilize non-blocking operations ([`queue.put(block=False)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.put_nowait) and [`queue.get(block=False)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get_nowait)) in your favour when you're set on what you need.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @ReutSharabani - haven't used `Queue` so far, so the edit is much appreciated; will take me a while to wrap my head around this `:)` In any case, it looks like this will work - accepted for now; cheers!